# Use generics in place of a dedicated variable enum

Tags: swift

I have a protocol. This is implemented by many `structs` that fall into one of two types of category: `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo`. I want to be able to distinguish between their types, so I've added an enum `ProtocolType` that defines the types `typeOne` and `typeTwo`. By default I set the `protocolType` to be `typeOne`, but I manually specify `typeTwo` when it's a TypeTwo struct:

```
enum ProtocolType {
  case typeOne
  case typeTwo
}

protocol MyProtocol {
  let name: String { get }
  var protocolType: ProtocolType { get }
}

extension MyProtocol {
  var protocolType: ProtocolType {
    return .typeOne
  }
}

enum TypeOne {
  struct Foo: MyProtocol {
    let name = "foo"
  }
}

enum TypeTwo {
  struct Bar: MyProtocol {
    let name = "bar"
    let protocolType = .typeTwo
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can remove the necessity for defining `protocolType` in all structs and somehow use generics to identify what type a struct is? They're already defined under the `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo` convenience enums, I was wondering if I could utilise that some how?

Comment: So you want all the structs in the `TypeTwo` enum to have `protocolType == .typeTwo` and all the structs in the `TypeOne` enum to have `protocolType == .typeOne`, without declaring `protocolType` explicitly? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Hmm… I feel like there is a better way of approaching this problem in general. Can you explain a bit more about the underlying problem and maybe there is a more elegant way to structure the data to solve it without the complexity of protocols and enums etc…

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with what you're doing. How is it any different from your protocol declaring a Bool variable requirement? There is something here that's either true or false. What's bad about that? If that's the way you need it to be, that's the way you need it to be.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is what you think this has to do with _generics_. This seems like another case where people just throw the word "generic" at the wall like spaghetti without any clear idea what it means.

Comment: It is hard to visualize what you are trying to do, and help you. What is the point of specifying `protocolType` when `Foo` is always `TypeOne.Foo` and `Bar` is always `TypeTwo.Bar`. You should be able to use something like `object is TypeOne.Foo` or `object is TypeTwo.Bar` to differentiate

Comment: you can create a "Type2" protocol by inheriting "MyProtocol". so myprotocol will have default value to type1 and MyProtocol2 will have default value to type2. You just need to inherit type2 structs from "MyProtocol2" instead of "MyProtocol" and then you don't need to specify type explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given some protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  var name: String { get }
}
```

It sounds like you want to "tag" certain types as special, even though they have the same requirements. That's not an enum, that's just another type (protocol):

```
// No additional requirements
protocol SpecialVersionOfMyProtocol: MyProtocol {}
```

You can then tag these at the type level, not the value level:

```
struct Foo: MyProtocol {
    let name = "foo"
}

struct Bar: SpecialVersionOfMyProtocol {
    let name = "bar"
}
```

And you can tell the difference using `is` if you need to:

```
func f<T: MyProtocol>(x: T) {
    if x is SpecialVersionOfMyProtocol {
        print("special one")
    }
}
```

---

In most cases, though, I wouldn't use this kind of runtime check. I'd just have two protocols (one for TypeOne and one for TypeTwo), and implement whatever you need as extensions on those. For example, say you want to print the name differently depending on the type. Start with a protocol that just expresses that:

```
protocol NamePrintable {
    var name: String { get }
    func printName()
}

func printIt<T: NamePrintable>(x: T) {
    x.printName()
}
```

Then extend that for TypeOnes and TypeTwos:

```
protocol TypeOne: NamePrintable {}

extension TypeOne {
    func printName() {
        print("I'm a type one with the name \(name)")
    }
}

protocol TypeTwo: NamePrintable {}

extension TypeTwo {
    func printName() {
        print("I'm a type two with the name \(name)")
    }
}
```

And conform your structs:

```
struct Foo: TypeOne {
    let name = "foo"
}

struct Bar: TypeTwo {
    let name = "bar"
}

printIt(x: Foo()) // I'm a type one with the name foo
printIt(x: Bar()) // I'm a type two with the name bar
```

If you want a default implementation, you can hang it on NamePrintable, but I kind of recommend not doing that for what you've described. I'd probably just have "type one" and "type two" explicitly.

```
extension NamePrintable {
    func printName() {
        print("BASE FUNCTIONALITY")
    }
}
```

Comment: You went above and beyond for this answer, thank so much! And the first way seems more like what I want. I'm trying to run a function, only if the type of the object is `TypeTwo`, rather than `TypeOne`. And you're right in saying that they have the same requirements.

Comment: One question, if `func f<T: MyProtocol>(x: T)` was actually `func f(x: MyProtocol)`, what difference would it make when checking `if x is SpecialVersionOfMyProtocol`?

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference for that. `is` always uses the runtime type. Using the generic (the first) rather than the existential (the second) just is more efficient, and generally what the Swift team recommends when either will work. https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-introduce-existential-any/53520